# C Buffer overflow Display message (Using Ubuntu and DDD)

Tags: c, ubuntu, buffer, buffer-overflow, ddd-debugger

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void badf(int n, char c, char* buffer)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
    buffer[i]=c;
    }

}

void f(int n, char c)
{
    char buffer[16];
    badf(n,c,buffer);
}

void message ()
{
printf("Hello\n");

}

int main()
{
f(32,0x08048411);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code I got so far (got given the base of it and got to stick to it, thats why there is a badf and f function)

The goal is that the program prints the Hello message by overflowing to the Instruction pointer. Using Data display debugger in Ubuntu, I believe the address of this display is 0x0804811.

When I run the program through and use x/16x $esp the next address in the stack is just 1s (am guessing only the last two digits are being taken from the address above)

What am wondering is how I would make the next address the full address and not just the last two digits.

Also the 32 is calculated from 16 (buffer defined above) + 8 (base pointer) + 8 (Instruction pointer)

Thanks in advance for any help as I know this specific problem.

Comment: What you want to do doesn't make any sense... and if it did, this code does in turn not make any sense in achieving that. This is just random buggy code, with no relevance to anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not pass the address via an 8bit integer (`char`) but use a type wide enough ... - that is at least 32bits.

Modify as follows:

```
void badf(int n, unsigned int u, char* buffer)
...

void f(int n, unsigned int u)
...
```

Comment: Do you mean passing the address through as an array?

Comment: with the code you added I changed the u(s) to c(s) so it worked with my program. I had been trying different stuff so my buffer was set to 24 (not 32) running the code through DDD i noticed the address was present in the stack ("using x/16x $esp) now am trying different buffer sizes to see it it works.

Comment: @Dan1676 No he meant that storing the value 0x08048411 inside a char, which is most likely 1 byte large, is quite a bad idea. Also, if that is an address, then the original code doesn't make any sense at all.